# How to change a tms/xyz map projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, xyz, tile-map-service

I have the portion of a map stored as a collection of .jpg tiles in tms set of folders. The problem is that this particular set seems to have a WGS84 (EPSG 4326) projection, while my desired projection is a Spherical Mercator (EPSG 3857) one. The only adequate solution I found is to use tiff format and do a reprojection using some GDAL tools. But can I do this conversion directly from tms to tms?

P.S. That's how those maps look in QGIS. EPSG:3857 on the left and EPSG:4326 on the right:

[image]

Comment: usually you pick the grid set that matches your required projection or your client app handles reprojection for you.

Comment: I've sourced my map using SASPlanet, which got no option to pick the grid for tms export. And this map is supposed to match Google Maps/OpenStreetMap out of the box. I also tried to do this in QGIS and MapProxy but haven't found anything.

Comment: How do you infer the coordinate system for your tiles? Is there some metadata we can look at? Otherwise any slippy map program will assume they are standard Web Mercator tiles...

Comment: There are no metadata, just x y and z identifiers.

Comment: Is there any way you can make a couple of levels of these tiles available for us to experiment with? QGIS is assuming your tiles are Web Mercator because there's no other metadata, and the shrinking is because Web Mercator goes to +Inf at the north pole but 4236 has the N pole at +90 units. Web Mercator is therefore "stretched". But it might be recoverable if we can tell QGIS what these tiles are...

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded top five exemplary levels for world view [here](https://github.com/digitalrebel78/SASPlanet-export-example).

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there will be a 1-1 correspondence of tiles from one system to the other, so reprojecting tile-by-tile isn't going to work. The latitude span of tiles will be different as you go north, so tiles that are a set number of degrees in 4326 won't be a set number of metres in EPSG:3857.

So the EPSG:3857 tiles that you want will be reprojected parts of more than one tile.

If you can properly see your EPSG:4326 tiles as a layer in QGIS, in the correct place, you could use the QTiles plugin to create EPSG:3857 tiles. I think QTiles will only produce EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) tiles no matter what the project CRS is set to (from some little experiments I've just done...).

Comment: Well, I can open it in QGIS and I get a proper 1 to 2 correspondence between my ESPG:4326 map and EPSG:3857 OSM reference map. Is it a correct place or should they match?

Comment: What's a "1 to 2" correspondence? Are your tiles exactly half (or double) an EPSG:3857 tile?

Comment: The whole map appears to be shrunk twice according to OSM. I've added a picture.